# Check objects inside same array and different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm studying a bit of js objects lately (I'm still learning). I'm stucked on a project of mine where I need to check if 2 objects inside an array (of objects) are identical between them and between them and another object in a different array. These two initial objects will have to behave differently if certain instances occurs:

I'll try to be as clear as possible. My code has 2 arrays of objects:

```
let array1 = [{name: "New York", value: "A", price: 43, status: "not checked"},
             {name: "Not Specified", value: "A", price: 333, status: "not checked"},
             {name: "Barry", value: "C", price: 48, status: "not checked"},..etc.];

let array2 = [{name: "John", value: "A", price: 23, status: "not checked"},
             {name: "Jerry", value: "A", price: 67, status: "not checked"},
             {name: "Barry", value: "C", price: 48, status: "not checked"},                 
             {name: "Tom", value: "F", price: 23, status: "not checked"},
             {name: "Barry", value: "C", price: 48, status: "not checked"},...etc.];
```

As you can see initial status of every objects is "not checked". Now, part of my code loops one array (array2, the bigger of the two) to check if, at the same position "i", they have objects inside with different properties/values:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    if (array1[i].value != array2[i].value){
    ...do something...}.
```

Now, as you can see there is also one result in common in array1 and array2:

```
{name: "Barry", value: "C", price: 48, status: "not checked"}
```

What I would like to do is this:

- staying inside the original for loop, when I arrive at "i" position of "Barry", I want to check if in array2 there are at least 2 objects
  identical between them (in this case the "Barry" one). If yes then:
- check if these two are identical to any object in array1 (always "Barry", this time in array1,
  here
  the "i" position can be random).
  If yes then:
- while the loop is still cycling at "i" position of the first "Barry" result, the first result will do something, while the other identical one (always in array2) will behave differently (so I was thinking to modify the status of the first result to "checked", so the subsequent result, will have to verify that having a different status, "not checked", need to behave differently). Nothing happens to the result in array1.

I'm sorry for the wall of text, but being pretty noob is hard to describe sometimes what I'm trying to do. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: You're only comparing the objects at the same indexes in the two arrays. You need nested loops so you compare every object in one array with every object in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call a `find` function for each element in the first array.  Something like this:

```
array1.forEach(item => {
  var found = array2.find(item2 => item2.value === item.value)
  if (found) {
    // do something
  }
}
```